# copy sqlite DB From Inbox to documents directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

when open sqlite file from mail it come to folder named inbox in my documents directory 
and i use this code to copy this file to document directory

```
- (void) copyAdd
{
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *databasePath;

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,        YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* inboxPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Inbox"];

// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"CAT.sqlite"]];

if(![filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]){

    [filemgr copyItemAtPath:inboxPath toPath:databasePath error:nil];





    NSLog( @"copy create database");
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"sucess" message:@"COPY CAT DB"         delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"dismis" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}else{
    NSLog( @"Failed to open/create database");

}
```

it create folder with name CAT.sqlite and inside this folder i found the dataBase CAT.sqlite

how can i copy the file named CAT.sqlite from Inbox folder to document directory without create folder with the same name .

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: it need to copy the data base to document directory without create any folder also need to delete the old data base from the inbox when receive new one with the same name

Comment: If you have a particular problem to solve then this is the right site to ask the questions you might have.  However we aren't here to implement functionality on your behalf; we don't work for you.  So have a go and edit your question with specific issues you are facing, including details of what isn't working and any error messages you received.

Comment: I think i ask about specific thing that thing is why folder created instead of copy the data base and i put the code that i use so please if you don't know why please don't bother me

Comment: The code you posted tries to copy the `Indbox` folder to a file named `CAT.sqlite`. You need a path to the file in the `Inbox` folder and you want to move that file, not the `Inbox` folder.

Comment: @EGCat BTW - "trojanfoe" is right. You have not asked a question nor have you told us what your issue is. So far you have only posted some code and told us what you want to do. The proper thing to do is actually ask a question and/or point out what issue you are having with the posted code.

Comment: @maddy you touch the point "The code you posted tries to copy the Indbox folder to a file named CAT.sqlite." i need to copy the file named CAT.sqlite to the document directory not to another folder ??

Answer (score 0):

this is my code that solve the problem the only missing thing is to specify the file name that i need to copy from the inbox folder not the all folder but CAT.sqlite folder

```
 - (void) copyAdd
{
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *databasePath;

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* inboxPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Inbox"];
NSString *filePath = [inboxPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CAT.sqlite"];

// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"CAT.sqlite"]];

if(![filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]){

    //        NSLog(@"dbPAth : %@",dbPAth);
    [filemgr copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:databasePath error:nil];





    NSLog( @"copy create database");
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"sucess" message:@"COPY CAT DB" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"dismis" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}else{
    NSLog( @"Failed to open/create database");

}



}
```